# Uninstall a python version doesnt show up on programs

Tags: python

My py -0e shows two version:
3.19
3.7

I need the 3.7 uninstalled, but the programs/features on windows only shows the python launcher installation.
I checked the folder for 3.7 - but it has nothing to uninstall. Neither is there anything for 3.19.

I see multiple registry entries for 3.7 which means it was probably installed properly.
But i don't see any option to cleanly uninstall - so the references are removed.
The 3.19 is updated and marked as the default at windows variables and also when i use the py -0e.
ANy help would be greatly appreciated

I see multiple registry entries for 3.7 which means it was probably installed properly.
But i don't see any option to cleanly uninstall - so the references are removed.
The 3.19 is updated and marked as the default at windows variables and also when i use the py -0e.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click "Uninstall a Program"
3. Scroll down to Python and click uninstall for 3.7  version which is the one you don't want anymore.

Comment: The programs/features on windows only shows the python launcher version which is 3.19. Thats the only version available to uninstall. i need the lower version to be removed

Comment: Did you check C:\python37?

Comment: enterprise install. it generally in a standard non-os drive. we have multiple installs in different locations, and i need to uninstall the lower version which doesnt show up in apps removal and i also dont have the installation binary available.

Comment: Did you check the path environment variable's to see where they could be located?

Comment: I have the location with the install. It's also on the registry entries for windows, but i don't see any way to cleanly uninstall which is what I'm trying to do. The updated versions are all good. I just need the obsolete version uninstalled cleanly

Comment: Can you tell me where the location of the installation is? You might be able to remove directory of that python version.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the installer for python 3.7, you can open it and select uninstall.

Comment: The programs/features on windows only shows the python launcher version which is 3.19. Thats the only version available to uninstall. i need the lower version to be removed

Comment: and i dont have the installer - this is a windows server which wont let me downlaod the installer anymore since its an obsolete version.

Comment: Understood, not everyone keeps the installers later. You can try what @111 said.